# Oracle HS (12c)

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to set up HS from a 12c database that will eventually send data across to a remote MySQL server.

I have installed the odbc driver;

```
root ~ # rpm -ivh mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

This is my `listener.ora` file;

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ap-ora-records-test.ap.local)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

This is my `tnsnames.ora` file;

```
RECORDSDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ap-ora-records-test.ap.local)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = recordsdb.ap.local)
    )
  )

MYSQL =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ap-ora-records-test.ap.local)(PORT=1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MYSQL))
    (HS=OK)
  )
```

I connected to the database, and created the database link;

```
SQL> CREATE DATABASE LINK MYSQL
  2  CONNECT TO "root" IDENTIFIED BY "removed"
  3  USING 'mysql';
```

Restarting the lsnrctl;

```
./bin/lsnrctl reload
./bin/lsnrctl stop
./bin/lsnrctl start
./bin/lsnrctl status
./bin/lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 08-SEP-2014 10:54:42

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                08-SEP-2014 10:42:05
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 12 min. 37 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/log/diag/tnslsnr/ap-ora-records-test/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ap-ora-records-test.ap.local)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ap-ora-records-test.ap.local)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "recordsdb.ap.local" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "recordsdb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "recordsdbXDB.ap.local" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "recordsdb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

As well as `tnsping`;

```
oracle /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1 $ ./bin/tnsping ap-ora-records-test

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 08-SEP-2014 10:42:44

Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=::1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
OK (0 msec)
```

I then tried getting a piece of data - `SQL> SELECT * from MYSQL.users@mysql;` which gave the following result;

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from MYSQL
```

Where am I going wrong?

edit 1:

This is my creation code;

```
CREATE SHARED PUBLIC DATABASE LINK mysql_remote_shared
CONNECT TO root IDENTIFIED BY password
AUTHENTICATED BY root IDENTIFIED BY password
USING 'mysql';
```

Comment: Did you try creating the DBLink a public database link?

Comment: Updated the original post!

Comment: What does your .odbc.ini file for the oracle user look like?  You need to setup a odbc entry there for the particular mysql database you want to connect to.

Comment: Also IIRC MySQL is configured to disallow remote connections for the root user.  Better to set-up a new mysql user for the link and allow it to only connect from the oracle server.